# Go compiler produces strange load into x0

Tags: go, riscv

I am using Go 1.14 with linux/riscv64 target, and I'm compiling a hello world where I am seeing this in the assembly:

```
1b078:       04813183                ld      gp,72(sp)
1b07c:       00018003                lb      zero,0(gp)
1b080:       00313423                sd      gp,8(sp)
```

As you can see there is a load to zero from [GP+0], which should be an "exception or whatever" according to the specification:

> Loads with a destination of x0 must still raise any exceptions and cause any other side effects even though the load value is discarded.

What exactly is going on here? Is the compiler producing erroneous output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know anything about go on riscv but this is a common pattern.
The memory access only checks that [gp+0] is accessible and readable, without actually reading.
This is useful for cases like:

```
func f(a *[0x100001]byte) {
    (*a)[0x100000] = 1;
}
```

The compiler must generate the following pseudo code:

```
check_not_null(a)
store(a + 0x100000, 1)
```

The null check can be implemented using the same construct that you’ve discovered, without branches.

Comment: That makes sense. I suppose it's a no-op once the memory protections have been checked.